# Select Statement comparing data between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select all the rows where the timestamp is greater than the timestamp stored in a separate table. What I tried initially:

```
SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `Timestamp` > `LoggedIn`;
```

In this situation, Timestamp is in chat and LoggedIn is in onlinestatus. I'm pretty sure this is simple but several google searches have yielded no results that I could understand

Comment: This should work, depending on exactly WHAT the types of those fields are, and what the values in them are.

Comment: You need to `JOIN` the other table.

Comment: How are both tabes related to each other?

Comment: What was the result when you tried it?  Was there an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    columns
FROM
    chat
    JOIN onlinestatus ON (chat.id = onlinestatus.chat_id)
WHERE
    Timestamp > LoggedIn
```

The `chat.id` and `onlinestatus.chat_id` columns are made up, but there has to be some column that points one to the other.  Make sure to join on this column.

Comment: I'm still a little fuzzy on join but that did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Select * from chat where timestamp > (select timestamp from online status)try this. You can add User id where if you want.